# How do I obtain JSON from a algolia places search?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, algolia

I was following the Algoias's Places Documentation, I have my input that searches cities with the Algolia API engine, but I want to get a JSON format response from my query (something like I see in this demo: https://community.algolia.com/places/), I am following the documentation, but I am really hard stuck :(.

Is it possible?

```
//This is my JS code, it just converts my input into a places search, I remove the AppId and the ApiKey just for show here!

var placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'Here goes my AppId, I remove it for show here',
    apiKey: 'Here goes my ApiKey, I remove it for show here',
    container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
  });
```

Comment: I am not sure how it is supposed to work. But have you checked their events section?
https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#events
It would be very helpful if you could provide a working jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Thank you so much, that did work, @AndrejsGubars!